# How to add Custom Metadata to Pdf using Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, jspdf

I want to add custom metadata to a pdf file using javascript. is there any package that can help.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/coherentpdf can do this. See Chapter 11 of the manual for functions like `setMetadataFromByteArray` and others.